# Star rating readonly in html email

Tags: html, email, html-email

I've a data coming from backend source in **numeric** form which will determine the rating. Numeric value ranges from 0-5 and **can be 0.5,1.5,2.5** etc etc.

Number can be 2.5 and 2 and a half stars would be filled with Gold color or any accordingly.

Now I've been trying to do different things but failing constantly. I've tried using that value in data-attr and then applying styles according to the value but email doesn't cater the data-attr IMO (not working for me).Positioning also doesn't work. Background image support is buggy. So, I'm kind of stuck. If there's any workaround please it'll be a great help. I'm only looking for outlook and windows 10 mail right now.

My codepen (but not sure):

https://codepen.io/kenny-kk/pen/eYgMEej

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>★</li>
  <li>★</li>
  <li class="active">★</li>
  <li>★</li>
  <li>★</li>
</ul>
```

Here's a guide for css support in email:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: please add your try. what goes wrong?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure how to do it. I've edited my post

Comment: The problem with HTML email is that it totally depends on the client being used and many (most?) of them do not even use a regular up-to-date major browser engine.

Comment: Why is this tagged [javascript]? Are you using JS to dynamically generate the email content?

Comment: @Bergi I was earlier, I now changed it to how Ammar F-A has explained in comments section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd be better if you use the images instead of these Unicode stars. If your data is coming from backend maybe store it in **data-attr** and according to the value, show the image. For this you've to keep separate images in your code (I'm afraid that's the only way). Image support is provided by all the mailing platforms.

```
mso-hide:all;
```

This will keep your images hidden, be sure to use this on **div** element. Use this style to unhide the image for that rating star.

```
[data-star="2.5"]{
mso-hide: unset;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript isn't supported in email due to security concerns.

There are potential 'interactive' solutions which utilise form inputs like checkboxes & radio buttons but email client support may be sketchy and I doubt there will be support in Outlook or Windows 10 Mail.

Another solution is to use links with URLs holding the rating value i.e. `http://example.com/?rating=5`, in which case you'll need a process on your website to catch these values and update the user's rating accordingly.

Some resources:

- Using Star Ratings to Collect Feedback via Email - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/using-star-ratings-to-collect-feedback-via-email/
- A Campaign Monitor dev's example from a few years back - https://dabblet.com/gist/6944624
- Codepen example - https://codepen.io/maxxscholten/pen/zxegjL?editors=1000

Ultimately, you won't find a solution which works like website forms.

Comment: Thanks for the response but what I'm actually looking is the way to "read-only" stars. I'm not trying to rate through email. I have a rating number and I just ant to show stars (uneditable) based on that rating value. 4 stars will be shown if value is 4.

Comment: @Kenny.k - Okay, so can't you just show an image of the stars? OR even still use the code above and remove the links. Really simple.